# Is it possible to restart a Raspberry Pi after OS shutdown?

Tags: boot

While SSHing into my Raspberry Pi, I got distracted. I attempted to shut down my PC using `sudo shutdown now`, but because I was still connected, I accidentally shut down the Raspberry Pi instead. This closed the connection and left me unable to connect to it.

I was able to restart it by calling someone who was near the Raspberry Pi to pull the plug out and back in.

Is there a way I can restart it remotely without having to depend on someone to be physically present?

Comment: You can probably disable shutdown, and only allow restart.  For wheezy raspian, something like this but use "no" everywhere, and remove the restart action: http://superuser.com/a/461996/27510

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the answer is no. You could use something like wake-on-lan, but this isn't supported by the Pi.

Comment: Without additional hardware?  No.  However, if you are creative and willing to get your hands dirty, you could rig up a small circuit that uses the output from a GPIO pin (use an alias that first writes to the pin, waits, and then initializes the real restart sequence), uses that to charge a capacitor, which controls a timing circuit connected to a relay controlling the power source of the Pi.

Comment: @InkBlend Way beyond me; very innovative!

Comment: Maybe two pi boards rigged so one can power cycle the other if needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just came across it.  I did this using the P6 pin holes on the pi just to the left of the dvi plug.  That is the reset switch.  You can solder a dual pin connector on these holes and plug a pushbutton swith in.  When the pi is shutdown, you can hit the switch and it will start back up.

the disclaimer is you will void the warranty if you solder on the board.  I stole my pushbutton switch from an old computer and mounted it onto the plastic pi case.

Comment: I liked doing it this way because you're not canabalizing GPIO pins